# What values are saved when creating object from same class

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, global-variables

Say I have an ArrayList of Objects in my main-class, lets say they are dogs, and I create like this `ArrayList <Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();`

Now lets say that in this `Dog`-Class there is a global array of booleans:

```
boolean[] eyes= new boolean[2];
eyes[0] = true;
eyes[1] = true;
```

I create my first `Dog` in my main-class, in the contructor of `Dog`, the `Dog` loses an eye, and the `Array` of booleans in `Dog` now looks like this:

```
boolean[] eyes= new boolean[2];
eyes[0] = true;
eyes[1] = false;
```

If I now go back to my main-class and create another `Dog`, will this dog also have one eye? or will it be created with two eyes like the first dog?

Feel free to give this a new title, I had no idea how to frase the question.

EDIT: By global I mean a variable created and initiated outside of the constructor or any other method, like so:

```
public class Dog{
boolean[] eyes= new boolean[]{true, true};

public Dog(){
//...
}
}
```

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without seeing `Dog`'s constructor. Also, what do you mean by "global array"?

Comment: Your example in the edit isn't valid Java. You can create the array to attach to the `eyes` variable (which belongs to the particular `Dog` instance, since it is not `static`), but assigning values like that has to be done in a constructor or other method. (Alternatively, you could use `new boolean {true, true}`.)

Comment: Ye, changed it, shouldn't code after 3am when in a rush ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, variables can belong to either the class itself or to instances of that class. Instance variables are the usual ones and have to be set up in the constructor or some other method, and they are not shared at all between different instances of the class.  Class variables are declared with the keyword `static`, and they are shared among all instances of that class (a change on one changes all).

Comment: (As a note: Even initialization statements like `private int numEyes = 2;` take place inside the constructor. It is often more readable to place the value with the declaration, but the compiler moves the assignment into the constructor code.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by global. If the variable is static, then yes, all dogs will have the same array. If it is an instance variable, then it would only be for that specific dog.

Answer (score 0):

Every new object has it's own behavior, so, the second dog is different from the first dog, suppose you buy 2 dogs, the first is female and second is male, they are different, but both of them are Dog.

You can buy rope for both of them, meaning sharing some information through all objects, it means create `static fields`, if you want all dogs have 2 eyes, just create one static field and it'll automatically shared through all objects.

Comment: Each object has its own copies of instance fields, but all objects of the same class share all of their behavior.

Comment: Each object does not have its own behavior. (Those are separate classes.) All objects of the same class share all of their behavior.